# How to configure p6spy to redirect its output into a file

Tags: java, spring, logging, p6spy, log4jdbc

I was able to successfully configure [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) to intercept the JDBC calls and output them to Eclipse's console.  However, I'd like to have those logs with the binding parameters captured in the file.  Could someone please give me a hand on how to to that.  Here are my current configurations:

## log4j.properties

```
# Default log level
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console, FileAppender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

# DEBUG File
log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=claims_logger.log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN

 log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=ERROR


log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN

log4j.logger.org.mule=INFO
log4j.logger.org.mule.modules.sqs=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.fuwt=DEBUG
```

## spy.properties

```
realdriver=org.postgresql.Driver
useprefix=false
deregisterdrivers=true
module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory

executionthreshold=

outagedetection=false
outagedetectioninterval=

filter=false

include     =

exclude     =

sqlexpression =

autoflush   = true

dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

includecategories=

excludecategories=info,debug,result,batch

stringmatcher=

stacktrace=false

stacktraceclass=

reloadproperties=false


reloadpropertiesinterval=60


appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.StdoutLogger
append=true

log4j.additivity.p6spy=false

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=p6spy - %m%n


log4j.logger.p6spy=DEBUG,STDOUT
```

Spring is building its datasource using:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver
```

I'm using P6Spy version 1.3.

I read that log4jdbc is a preferred way of doing SQL interception for my use case, however it seems it requires slightly more configuring, i.e. one needs to modify jdbc URL as per [their doc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/#4._Prepend_jdbc:log4_to_the_normal_jdbc_url_that_you_are_using.).  Any experience on how parameter capture is done in either frameworks and redirected to a file is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there's a difference between the namespaces for appender classes in p6spy between its major versions.  We happened to be using version 1.3 of p6spy where FileLogger appender resides in:

```
appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.FileLogger
```

Mistakenly, we were using the following configuration, which pertains to version 2.x of p6spy:

```
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger
```

and that lead to wrong behavior.

What clued us on to this was more thorough examination of the console log where the following line was discovered:

```
Cannot instantiate com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger, even on second attempt.  Logging to file log4jaux.log: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use FileAppender and specify a log file, as seen in https://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/configandusage.html

```
    # specifies the appender to use for logging
    # Please note: reload means forgetting all the previously set
    # settings (even those set during runtime - via JMX)
    # and starting with the clean table 
    # (only the properties read from the configuration file)
    # (default is com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger)
    #appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.Slf4JLogger
    #appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
    #appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger

    # name of logfile to use, note Windows users should make sure to use forward slashes in their pathname (e:/test/spy.log) 
    # (used for com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger only)
    # (default is spy.log)
    #logfile = spy.log
```

Comment: Thanks -- I tried exactly that before posting but it didn't work for me.  Are you using that configuration yourself and it's working? I had both   #appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
#appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger  uncommented, not sure if it matters.

Comment: I'm not using p6spy, but found that after searching in p6spy project website. I'm pretty sure "appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger" is overriding "appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger" in your case, so maybe you should try again after commenting "StdoutLogger" line.